# Rails, ActiveRecord - how to get count rows in relation :belons_to?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, select, count

I have the model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article
end
```

In the controller I am fetching all category names

```
@categories = Category.order('name')
```

How could I fetch all categories and sort them by the count of most used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change `has_one :article` to `has_many :articles`.

So my version:

```
Category.joins(:articles)
        .select("categories.*, count(articles.id) as counter")
        .order("counter")
```

Comment: my app is running on PostgreSQL, so I had to update little bit your query: `Category.joins(:articles)
        .select("categories.*, count(articles.id) as counter")
        group('categories.id').order("counter DESC, name")`. The problem is, that if I have in the Article table `category_id` **2** (eg. "Sport"), **2** (eg. "Sport") and **3** (eg. "News"), so the query print on the first position **Sport** with 2 items and on the 2. - 10. position the rest, and every category has printed 1 item. How is that possible? **Sport** should have 2 items, **News** 1 item and the rest 0.

Comment: I don't understand what you're toking about. Edit your question to clarify what do you want exactly.